# How to disable or not show any headers for StickyListHeaders from emilsjolander

Tags: android, listview, sticky

I am using https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders as my primary listview for most of my app. I have put this listview in my one layout that I use for all my listviews. However, There are some instances when I don't want to show any headers, I just want to show a regular list, like a listview.

Is there a way to set StickyListHeaders to not show headers at all? There are options for making headers not sticky. I want the headers to just not show up, is that possible with the existing API?

```
    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // do nothing
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getHeaderId(int position) {
        // do nothing
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually there's a lot simpler way

```
@Override
public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return new View(parent.getContext());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement, and succeeded in patching StickyListHeaders to behave like a normal listview when getHeaderView returns null. Untill now, I have not yet run into side effects of this change:
https://github.com/mtotschnig/StickyListHeaders/commit/9252a6fe5367bc2421739bb5d34856343236dd24

Answer (score 1):

Try this out to disable sticky list view header:

```
    @Override
    public View getHeaderView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        convertView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String headerText = "";


        } else if (position > mainList.size() - 1) {
            headerText = "Categories";
        } else {
            headerText = "";
            return new View(getActivity());
        }

        holder.text1.setText(headerText);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this requirement recently and ended up patching version 2.3.0 of the library to allow null headers: https://github.com/xlsior/StickyListHeaders/tree/null-headers